# Using .ajaxSubmit from the jquery.form.js library

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble getting the .ajaxSubmit to fire. I'm using the jquery form plugin by Malsup, and have used it many times before without any issues. Here is my current code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="massemail" action="massmail.php">
<label for="subject">Subject:</input><input type="text" name="subject" class="subject">    <br><br><br>
<label for="message">Message:</input><textarea name="message" class="message"></textarea><br>
<input type="button" id="submitbutton" value="Send Email">
</form>
</body>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $( "#submitbutton" ).click(function() {
      $("#massemail").delay(500).ajaxSubmit({url: 'massmail.php', type: 'post'})
   });
});
```

Not sure why I can get .ajaxSubmit to fire in another file, with this same code, just a different URL file ({url: 'submitinfo.php',). Here is my massmail.php file:

```
<?php

$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$headers = 'From: info@email.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: info@email.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$query = sprintf("SELECT email FROM user_info");

$result = mysql_query($query);

$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $email = $row['email'];
    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($count % 5 == 0) {
      sleep(5); 
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

All of my paths are correct, so I'm not sure why I can't get this to work. Does anyone see any mistakes anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to swap two script files. jQuery goes first.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Wow.. Can't believe something as simple as this, caused me so much trouble. Thanks a bunch!